# Don't understand why my function is not being called

Tags: python, function, call

```
print ("Hello, User :)")
def search():
    answer = phrase.find(search)
    return answer

y = "Y"
while y == "Y":

    phrase = input("Please enter a phrase any phrase: ")
    print ("Thank you User - the phrase you entered reads as follows: ")
    print (phrase)

    search = input("Please enter one of the words of the phrase you just entered, or some consecutive characters from that phrase, and I will search for them: ")
    print ("Thank you, User")
    print ("Your word or characters are located at the following index location: ")
    search()
    #print (answer)

    y = input("Thanks for playing.  Would you like to play again(Y/N)?: ")
else:
    print ("Goodby, User")
```

Hoping someone can help why my function definition cannot be called.

Comment: What is this: `def search():
    answer = phrase.find(search)
    return answer`?

Comment: `search = input()` changes `search` to reference the input string, so you can't call it as a function.

Comment: thanks, so I changed the search variable, and I don't get the error anymore however I am not getting the index value result now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your function can't be the same as the variable name. Just change the `search` variable name like this:

```
search_ = input("Please enter one of the words of the phrase you just entered, or some consecutive characters from that phrase, and I will search for them: ")

search()
```

Also if you want the result to be printed out call the function like this:

```
print(search())
```

Comment: you are the man thanks a bunch

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer, if you have enough reputation to do so. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.